# Ruby: Pass super into another method to execute conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that looks like this:

```
 if args
   eval("super(#{args.join(',')})")
 else
   super
 end
```

twice in a method. I'd like to move it so that my code looks more like:

```
def special_method
  if a
    some_block do
      call_super(args, super_method)
    end
  else
    call_super(args, super_method)
  end
end

def call_super(args, super_method)
  if args
    eval("super(#{args.join(',')})")
  else
    super
   end
 end
```

I need to have a reference to the `super` I want to call (super `special_method`), since if I just create a method `call_super` and call `super`, it calls `call_super` on the superclass instead.

Does any of this make sense? x_x

Comment: @spickermann: no, it's a fail-prone way of writing `super(*args)`. The commas are not passed as a part of the parameter, they separate arguments in the call to `super`. (But the arguments better not be anything more complex than integers...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense except for why you would ever need it. `super` already passes any parameters that the current method receives. `super()` passes no params. `super(*args)` passes any params in `args`, or no params if `args` is `[]` or `nil`.

If you actually want to do what your code currently does (pass `args` if they are non-`nil`, but current method's params if not) and not what I think you wanted, you can write `args ? super(*args) : super` as a short alternative (you can't put this in another method since it wouldn't know what the current parameters are).

(Also, you will find that in 99% of cases you think `eval` is the answer, there is a better answer.)

**EDIT** in response to the comment:

if `args` is `['testing', 1]`, then `super(args)` will pass one parameter that is an array; `super(*args)` passes two parameters (a string and an integer):

```
# a module
module Foo
  def special_method
    # multiple arguments in `args`
    args = ['testing', 1]
    super(*args)
  end
end

class Bar
  # fixed number of arguments (without splats):
  def special_method(first, second)
    puts "First parameter:  #{first}"
    puts "Second parameter: #{second}"
  end
end

# subclass that includes the module
class Baz < Bar
  include Foo
end

Baz.new.special_method
# First parameter:  testing
# Second parameter: 1
```

(Note that "multiple arguments in `*args`" does not make sense, as `*args` is not a variable, `args` is).

I think one of the reasons for the confusion is the fact that splat has two different but related roles. In method definitions, they *collect* arguments into an array. Everywhere else, they *distribute* an array to an argument list.

```
require 'pp'

def foo(*args)
  pp args
end
foo([1, 2])  # all the parameters (namely, the one) collected into `args`
# [[1, 2]]
foo(1, 2)    # all the parameters (the two) collected into `args`
# [1, 2]
foo(*[1, 2]) # distribute `[1, 2]` to two parameters; collect both into `args`
# [1, 2]

def foo(args)
  pp args
end
foo([1, 2])  # all the parameters (the one that exists) passed as-is
# [1, 2]
foo(1, 2)    # all the parameters (the two) passed as-is, but method expects one
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
foo(*[1, 2]) # distribute `[1, 2]` to two parameters, but method expects one
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The reason why I resort to the eval() is because this is a module that will be included in several existing classes whose super methods have a fixed number of arguments (without splats). *args is an array of arguments that, if passed up to the super class, would come in as one argument and therefore break methods whose params require more than one argument. The eval() code I wrote is assuming that if you get multiple arguments in *args, e.g. ['testing', 1], it should call super('testing', 1) not super(['testing', 1]). Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: My thoughts are that you should review splats :) Edited in an example that follows your scenario as much as your details allow...

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thank you so much for your time and examples. This clears up all my questions.